# sudo fails with PERM_ROOT: setresuid(0, 0, 0): Operation not permitted

Tags: centos, sudo

I am working on a Centos7 server running on kernel version `3.10.0-862.2.3.el7` and when I invoke `sudo` (version `1.8.19p2`) to execute actions with administrative privileges I get the following error:

```
sudo: PERM_ROOT: setresuid(0, 0, 0): Operation not permitted
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I tried removing and re-installing the package. I checked the permission on the `sudo` executable, libraries and configuration files. I tried setting SELinux in permissive mode just in case it was messing with something. Unfortunately, nothing worked.

Does anyone has an idea of what could be the cause of such error?

Comment: Are you using any sort of user management integration (Kerberos, etc.)?  I see others with this problem fixing it with `service nscd stop; service nscd start`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti No, just a local user in the `wheel` group.

Comment: Has `sudo` worked on that system before? Is the SUID bit set? Is the volume mounted with `nosuid`? You can attach `strace` as root to the user shell which calls `sudo`: `strace -p $PID -f -o sudo.strace` That would give you the exact syscall which fails (may be `setresuid` but who knows).

Comment: @HaukeLaging I used to work on the system as root, so I wasn't using `sudo`. The FS is mounted normally and the SUID flag is set for the `sudo` executable. And here is the last part of the trace https://pastebin.com/raw/knWhqtBQ (I filtered just the `sudo` process)

Answer (score 2):

Compiling and installing the latest version of `sudo` from source fixed the problem. Evidently something was wrong in the way `yum` was installing the package.